# How can I find the source of data of a wolfram alpha query?

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

If in *Mathematica* I type, for example:

```
==Sun mass
```

Wolfram Alpha gives me lots of data (mass in kg, lb, sun radius, temperature...):

[image]

but where do they come from? How can I find the source of the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the plus icon at the bottom right corner. It will bring up a menu which shows you the source when available.

[image]

You should also take a look at the function StarData and it's documentation. Most data like this has an associated function with it that you can call and has more structure.

Comment: You can use `StarData["Sun", "Mass", "Source"]` in the notebook, which does list some sources.  I know that for other stars, mass is a computed property, but I don't know if this holds for the Sun as well.